# DFS on reversed graph

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I have to use DFS on a graph then on reversed graph and the graph is directed. I am curious that instead of first reversing the adjacency list into another adjacency list and then copying it back to original adjacency list and then invoking the DFS again, is there any way that i can write a DFS function knowing that i have to use the adjacency list in reversed way. Following is my Java code, and i am using it to tell whether my graph is strongly connected or not.I would be very helpful for help.In short, I want to avoid rev_graph funtion and minimize my code.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Strongly_conn
    {
     static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g;
     static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g1;
     static int []visited;
     public static void create_graph()
     {
      int n,i,k,j;
      Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter the value of number of vertices");
      n=s.nextInt();
      visited=new int[n];
      for(i=0;i<n;++i)
       visited[i]=0;
      g=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
      for(i=0;i<n;++i)
      {
       g.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
       System.out.println("enter the number of vertices adjacent to "+ (i+1)+" and what are they?" );         
       k=s.nextInt();
       for(j=1;j<=k;++j)
       g.get(i).add(s.nextInt());
      }      
     }
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
      int so,i;      
      Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      create_graph();
      System.out.println("enter any vertex");
      so=s.nextInt();
      DFS(so);
      for(i=0;i<g.size();++i)
       if(visited[i]==1)
       continue;
       else {System.out.println("the directed graph is not strongly connected");System.exit(0);}
      for(i=0;i<g.size();++i)
       visited[i]=0;
      rev_graph(); 
      DFS(so);
      for(i=0;i<g.size();++i)
       if(visited[i]==1)
        continue;
       else {System.out.println("the directed graph is not strongly connected");System.exit(0);}
      System.out.println("the directed graph is strongly connected"); 
     }
      public static void DFS(int s)
      {
       visited[s-1]=1;     
       for(int e:g.get(s-1))
        if(visited[e-1]==0)
       DFS(e);
       else continue;
      }
      public static void rev_graph()
      {
       int i;
       g1=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
       for(i=0;i<g.size();++i)
        g1.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
       for(i=0;i<g.size();++i)
       for(int e:g.get(i))
        g1.get(e-1).add(i+1);
       g=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(g1);
      }       
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Idea is when you traverse the graph as you visit a node put visited node in a stack, after putting all node in stack and then in reverse traversal method pop stack, you will get reversed order traversal of same graph. This most probably will work.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea here would be to traverse not to all the set nodes children but to its parents. Assuming you have an adjacency matrix (as pointed out by you), rather than looking for all the columns that are set, of the particular row, look at all the rows that are set for that node.

Example:

Say you have a graph like

```
1 -> 2
4 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
```

So your matrix would be:

```
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[1 0 1 0]
```

So here, as you can see node `1` has a child node `2` (from the first row). But if you look at columns (2nd column) `2` is a child of `1` and `3`. So you can add `1` and `3` to your stack and continue.

Comment: I specifically mentioned adjacency lists

Comment: So? How's it any different?

Comment: First, I resent your attitude. When a stranger is trying to help you, this is not how one responds. Second, if you cannot figure that out I think you need to go back to learning basics.

Comment: "Basics" say adjacency lists have better space complexity than adjacency matrix and this is my primary aim.

Comment: Chief, there is absolutely no difference. All you need to do is to map those lists with their children into a hash table and apply the same algorithm described above. The keys would be the node heads and the values would be children. In fact that makes it easier than a matrix. PS: You have a java tag on your post and still haven't been receiving any responses. There is a reason to that. Try to be humble, its always good.